# Must car rentals accept at least one payment method without a surcharge?

Tags: australia, fees, car, credit-card

This question is about paying the car hire fee *only*, not about making the security deposit (for which a credit card is understandably required).

Context: at least one Australian car rental company is applying mandatory credit/debit card surcharges. Your rental agreement says that the hire charge is say X, but in fact you have to pay 1.011 * X because of the surcharge. This is in their T&C, and their FAQ says that they won't take cash. They take cards only, and *all* card types are accepted with a surcharge.

Is it legal for them to form a contract for one amount, but only accept payment methods which result in paying *them* a higher amount?

Comment: @MichaelHall From memory, those questions are generally answered that cash must be accepted. But I suspect there could be some peculiarity around it in Australia, or in car rental market, or both.

Comment: @MichaelHall I see, okay, I've re-scoped the question.

Comment: you are paying them the rate and you pay for the costs they have depending on your card carrier. They just don't make the card costs part of the pricing.

Comment: @Trish Sure I get it, but _can_ they not make the card cost part of the price if they don't provide a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It is not a requirement for businesses to accept [cash](https://banknotes.rba.gov.au/legal/legal-tender/#:%7E:text=Australian%20banknotes%20are%20a%20legal,can%20be%20paid%20in%20coin.)

They can specify that contracts with the business must be settled in a specific way, and if that is done, then other methods of payment, including cash, are invalid.

### Businesses can charge card [surcharges](https://www.accc.gov.au/business/pricing/card-surcharges)

> Businesses can charge a surcharge for paying by card, but the surcharge must not be more than what it costs the business to use that payment type.
>
> If a business charges a payment surcharge, it must be able to prove the costs it is based on.
>
> **If there is no way for a consumer to pay without paying a surcharge, the business must include the surcharge in the displayed price.**

It is legal for them to form such a contract, but they are committing an offence by not displaying the price surcharge inclusive (s166 of the [ACL](https://www.legislation.gov.au/C2004A00109/latest/text/4)). Report them to the ACCC for enforcement; the law does not give you a private right of action.